Set inventory quantity of a Gelato product in Shopify via GraphQL API
In Shopify, I have a dropdown with the available locations. I'm integrating with gelato app.

Now, I am using Shopify GraphQL APIs (version 2024-10) and I thought this GraphQL query would have returned the locations
    locations(first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }

However, it seems that it doesn't consider app locations. I claim this because in the config I see

Which query should I run to get the location of the app gelato to update the stock inventory quantity?
